# JavaScript - how to get the range of numbers and return them in a string

Tags: javascript, string, range

I have two variables `num1` and `num2` which returns `1` and `7` respectively. I want to get the range of numbers `(2 3 4 5 6)` and include them to a string like `$("p#"+*The range of numbers*)` in JavaScript

I tried this:

```
    $(function(){
      num1 = 1;
      num2 = 7;
       str; 
      for (i = num1; i <= num2;i++){
        str = "p#"+i;
      }
        $(str).css({backgroundColor: "yellow");
    )};
```

When this code executes, the variable `str` return only the last number `7`. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to declare all your variables...

Comment: I have declared them all, `num1`, `num2`, and `str`

Comment: No, you have created implicit global variables, you need `var`.

Comment: you'd better write var in front of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
  var num1 = 1;
  var num2 = 7;
  var str = 'p#'; 
  for (i = num1; i <= num2;i++){
    str += i.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate onto your existing string.
Currently you are overwriting it with every iteration, which is why at the end it is the last value.

Do:
    `str += "p#"+i;`

instead of
   `str = "p#"+i;`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to have the 1 and 7 in your range of numbers you should do it like:

```
var str = "p#";
for (var i = num1 + 1; i < num2; i++){
    str += i;
}
```

and also be careful about declaring your variables.